# JQGrid-SetSelection Not working while edit cell is true

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have created a grid as below.I want the first row to be selected programmatically after the grid is loaded. Also the cell should be editable. The first row selection works fine with the cellEdit:false. When I make the cellEdit:true , the selection will not change if I click on other rows . The first row remains selected even if I click on other rows. Could anyone help please? Thanks in advance

```
        $("#grid").jqGrid({ 
            url : 'getGridData',
            datatype : "json",
            colNames : colNamesArray,
            colModel : colModelArray,
            rowNum:'',
            shrinkToFit:false,
            cellEdit : true,
            hidegrid: false,
            //loadonce: true,
            gridview:true,
            autowidth: true,
            height : gridHeight,
            cellSubmit : "remote",
            cellurl : "saveCelldata",
            gridComplete: function () {
                $("#grid").setSelection(1);
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/U4dcn/2

**Try this Updated fiddle**

```
 onSelectCell: function () {
        grid.resetSelection("83432a");
        }
```

I have added OnSelectCell Event to the code which will deselect the selected row,when u click any cell

Comment: I can see its working properly without celledit. But i need cell edit working. In your example there is no cell edit enabled.

Comment: cellEdit : Enables (disables) cell editing. When this option is set to true, onSelectRow event can not be used, and hovering is disabled (when mouseover on the rows). Source: [jqGrid - Cell Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing)   As you can see Row functionality gets disabled when Cell edit is enabled.So we cannot expect jqgrid to work like you expected,but if we make some tweaks on the CellEdit event  its possible

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/U4dcn/21/

Please add "editable:true".

```
colModel: [
        { name: 'PackageCode', index: 'PackageCode', width: "110",editable:true  },
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: "300",editable:true }
    ],
```